# Como quitar de una string aquella substring que tuvo como primera coincidencia con una regex de opción?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, regex, validación

```py
import re

def extraer(input_text_to_check):
    regex_patron_00A = r"(?:los |lo |el |las |la |mis |mi |sus |su |un |una |unos |unas )" #las opciones de aqui se quitan para la segunda opcion, lo cual genera problemas con la eleccion de una de las opciones

    regex_patron_00B = r"(?:es rr |es el )"

    x = re.split(regex_patron_00A, input_text_to_check, re.IGNORECASE)
    print(x)
    if len(x)!=2:
        return False

    print(x[1])
    x = re.split(regex_patron_00B, x[1])
    if len(x)!=2:
        return False

    return x


input_text_to_check = str(input())

x = extraer(input_text_to_check)

if (x != False):
    print("se valido")
    word = x[0]
    association = x[1]
    print(word)
    print(association)
```

Las opciones de `regex_patron_00A` se quitan en aqui se quitan en `x[1]` para la `regex_patron_00B`, lo cual genera problemas con la eleccion de las elecciones de la segunda regex.

Por ejemplo, con un `input_text_to_check = "avion es rr dispositivo"`

```
se valido
avion
dispositivo
```

pero si el input fuese:

`input_text_to_check = el avion es el dispositivo`

`input_text_to_check = los avion es el dispositivo`

Entonces fallaria incorrectamente:

```
['', 'avion es ', 'dispositivo']
```

ya que no puede tomar la opcion `es el` porque borro `el`, entonces lo que buscaba es una manera de quitar solo la coincidencia que se tuvo de la primera parte (y no todas las coincidencias posibles), y que se quite solo una vez, y no que quite, por ejemplo en este caso todos los `el` de la string.

---

Hay algo que tener el cuenta y es que la `association` podria ser una frase compuesta, por ejemplo : `el avion es el dispositivo volador`

Comment: Creo que te estas complicando innecesariamente con expresiones regulares, pero una solución en este caso podría ser usar en el primer split el parámetro que le dice cuantas divisiones de la cadena realizar como máximo, así: `re.split(regex_patron_00A, input_text_to_check, 1, re.IGNORECASE)`. Tambien puede funcionar dividir antes por la segunda expresión regular y después por la primera, pero esa es una solucíón muy _ad hoc_.

Comment: La salucion que han dado esta buena el unico problema es el supuesto de las palabras compuestas, por ejemplo que `association` fuese `"dispositivo volador"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo correctamente el problema, recibes una frase del estilo

```
x es el y
```

y hay que validar la expresión identificando `x` e `y`.

Para eso no son necesarias las expresiones regulares; se puede hacer en forma más simple:

1. Separa la frase en palabras usando `split`
2. Recorre la lista de palabras descartando todas los artículos (el, la, los, ...).
3. Las palabras que sobrevivan, agregalas a una lista.
4. Al final la lista debería contener las dos palabras deseadas.

--

```
articulos = ["el", "la", "los", "es"]

def extraer(input_text_to_check):
    resultado = []
    legal = False
    for palabra in input_text_to_check.split():
        if palabra in articulos:
            legal = True
        else:
            resultado.append(palabra)

    if len(resultado) == 2 and legal:
        return resultado[0], resultado[1]
    else:
        return None, None
```

Este es el código base, que necesitará ser ampliado para ir eliminado los errores de tipeo (como "rr") y otras situaciones anómalas.

#### Demo

```
articulos = ["el", "la", "los", "es"]

def extraer(input_text_to_check):
    resultado = []
    legal = False
    for palabra in input_text_to_check.split():
        if palabra in articulos:
            legal = True
        else:
            resultado.append(palabra)

    if len(resultado) == 2 and legal:
        return resultado[0], resultado[1]
    else:
        return None, None


#input_text_to_check = str(input())
tests = [
    "avion es rr dispositivo",
    "los avion es el dispositivo",
    "el avion es el dispositivo",
    "nada de nada"
]

for test in tests:
    print("Test: ", test)
    word, association = extraer(test)

    if word:
        print("se valido")
        print(word)
        print(association)
    else:
        print("no se valido")
```

produce:

```
Test:  avion es rr dispositivo
no se valido
Test:  los avion es el dispositivo
se valido
avion
dispositivo
Test:  el avion es el dispositivo
se valido
avion
dispositivo
Test:  nada de nada
no se valido

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias me re ayudo, y funciona perfecto con una lista extendida como esta:  `articulos = ["es aquel un", "es aquello un", "son aquellos unos", "son aquellas unas", "es aquel que", "es aquello que", "son aquellos que", "son aquellas que", "es a", "es un", "es una", "seria una", "seria uno", "serian unas", "serian unos", "son", "los", "lo", "las", "la", "el", "ella", "ellos", "ellas", "es", "seria", "serian", "son", "fue", "fueron", "fueran", "fueren", "fuesen", "mi", "mis", "mio", "tuyos", "tuyo", "unas", "unos", "una", "uno", "un"]`

Comment: El unico problema es si la palabra `y` fuera compuesta por ejemplo `dispositivo volador`

Answer (score 1):

Al final pude lograrlo con este code aunque creo que no es lo mas optimizado posible.

```py
def extract_info(input_text_to_check, learn_that):
    regex_patron_00A = r"(?:sabias que|sabes que|los |lo |el |las |la |mis |mi |sus |su )"

    continue_analyzing = False

    x = input_text_to_check

    m0 = re.search(regex_patron_00A, input_text_to_check, re.IGNORECASE)
    if m0:

        #if(re.search(pattern, string, flags[optional]) ): #Comprobador de si una subtring existe en una string

        if(re.search("sabias que", input_text_to_check)):
            x = x.replace("sabias que", "", 1)
            continue_analyzing = True

        elif(re.search("sabes que", input_text_to_check)):
            x = x.replace("sabes que", "", 1)
            continue_analyzing = True
        
        elif(re.search("los ", input_text_to_check)):
            x = x.replace("los ", "", 1)
            continue_analyzing = True

        elif(re.search("lo ", input_text_to_check)):
            x = x.replace("lo ", "", 1)
            continue_analyzing = True

        elif(re.search("las ", input_text_to_check)):
            x = x.replace("las ", "", 1)
            continue_analyzing = True

        elif(re.search("la ", input_text_to_check)):
            x = x.replace("la ", "", 1)
            continue_analyzing = True

        elif(re.search("mis ", input_text_to_check)):
            x = x.replace("mis ", "", 1)
            continue_analyzing = True

        elif(re.search("mi ", input_text_to_check)):
            x = x.replace("mi ", "", 1)
            continue_analyzing = True

        elif(re.search("sabias que", input_text_to_check)):
            x = x.replace("sus ", "", 1)
            continue_analyzing = True

        elif(re.search("sabias que", input_text_to_check)):
            x = x.replace("su ", "", 1)
            continue_analyzing = True

    print(x)

    word, association = "", ""

    if (continue_analyzing == True):

        regex_patron_m1 = r"\s*((?:\w+\s*)+) \s*\¿?(?:es aquel que a |es a |son aquellos que a |son los que a |son a |se deben a |es aquel que lo |es lo |son aquellos que lo |son los que lo |son lo |se deben a lo |se deben lo |es aquel que los |es los |son aquellos que los |son los que los |son los |se deben a los |se deben los |es aquel que el |es el |son aquellos que el |son los que el |son el |se deben a el |se deben el |es aquel que el |es el |son aquellos que el |son los que el |son el |se deben a el |se deben el |es aquel que la |es la |son aquellos que la |son los que la |son la |se deben a la |se deben la |es aquel que las |es las |son aquellos que las |son los que las |son las |se deben a las |se deben las |es aquel que le |es le |son aquellos que le |son los que le |son le |se deben a le |se deben le |es aquel que les |es les |son aquellos que les |son los que les |son les |se deben a les |se deben les |es aquel que|es |son aquellos que|son los que|son |se deben a |se deben|servirian como|servirian para|sirven para|sirven como|se usan para|se usan como|se utilizan como|son utilizados como|son usados como|son usadas como|es el |es la |son los |son las |es mi |son mis |es su |son sus |es un |son unos |es una |son unas )\s*((?:\w+\s*)+)\s*\??"

        m1 = re.search(regex_patron_m1, x, re.IGNORECASE) #Con esto valido la regex haber si entra o no en el bloque de code

        if m1:
            word, association = m1.groups()

            word = word.strip()
            association = association.strip()

            print(word)
            print(association)
            learn_that = True

    return learn_that, word, association



learn_that = False

learn_that, word, association = extract_info(input_text_to_check, learn_that)

if (learn_that == True):
        
    #Uso estas para las comparaciones, ya que sino las consideraria erroneamente como palabras que no estan en la lista solo por no tener el \n
    word_check = word + "\n"
    association_check = association + "\n"
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Además de lo que dice el bot Comunidad, tu código no está correctamente indentado. Por qué el codigo luego de learn_that = False está indentado?

Comment: Gracias cuando corte una parte del code quedo mal indentado pero ahi esta corregido